# How can I get my laptop's IP address automatically from within Java/Android

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a Android WebView with a laptop I use as a server. How I can get my laptop IP address **automatically** using java for my Android WebView?

Currently, I have to manually look up the IP address of my laptop and type it into my app code as follows: `webView.loadUrl("http://10.0.2.1/mylinks/");`

How can I automatically set that IP address?

Comment: Did you explore the features and configurations of your DHCP server? In case of statically assigned IP addresses, the hosts file might be even simpler to use.

Comment: Previously, i get my laptop ip address  from check manually on my laptop, with command on terminal `ifconfig` and i put that on my android webview `webView.loadUrl("http://myip/mylinks/");` > `webView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.1/mylinks/");`

so, my questions how i can get my laptop ip address automatically on my android webview.

so i do not have to put my laptop ip address manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the current IP address of your development machine to a Java constant at build time by adding the following to your app's build.gradle script.

Add to the `defaultConfig` section:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {

        //Set BuildConfig.DEVELOPER_MACHINE_IP to the IP address of any interface.
        def ipList = getLocalIPv4()
        buildConfigField("String", "DEVELOPER_MACHINE_IP", ipList.empty ? '""' : '"' + ipList.get(0) + '"')
    }
}
```

Then add the following method to the bottom of `build.gradle` after the `dependencies` section:

```
//return all v4 addresses
static def getLocalIPv4() {
    def ip4s = []
    NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()
            .findAll { it.isUp() && !it.isLoopback() && !it.isVirtual() }
            .each {
        it.getInetAddresses()
                .findAll { !it.isLoopbackAddress() && it instanceof Inet4Address }
                .each { ip4s << it.getHostAddress() }
    }
    return ip4s
}
```

Get the IP address anywhere in your program from the build config variable: `BuildConfig.DEVELOPER_MACHINE_IP`

```
package com.test.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toast.makeText( this,"The developer machine is " + BuildConfig.DEVELOPER_MACHINE_IP, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

For your webview, you would use the following:

```
webView.loadUrl("http://" + BuildConfig.DEVELOPER_MACHINE_IP + "/mylinks/");
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code traverse all the interface it has and then print the IPv4, IPv6 and mac address of the interface. For LAN IP address u can use a function 
**isSiteLocal()** which returns true if IP address is a local address.

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
public class App{

public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    // getting the list of interfaces in the local machine
    Enumeration<NetworkInterface> n = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    while( n.hasMoreElements()){ //for each interface
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------");
        NetworkInterface e = n.nextElement();
    //name of the interface
        System.out.println("Interface Name: " + e.getName());
    /* A interface may be binded to many IP addresses like IPv4 and IPv6
        hence getting the Enumeration of list of IP addresses  */
        Enumeration<InetAddress> a = e.getInetAddresses();
        while( a.hasMoreElements()){
            InetAddress addr = a.nextElement();
            String add = addr.getHostAddress().toString();
            if( add.length() < 17 )
                System.out.println("IPv4 Address: " + add);
            else
                System.out.println("IPv6 Address: " + add);
        }
        if(e.getHardwareAddress() != null){
                    // getting the mac address of the particular network interface
            byte[] mac = e.getHardwareAddress();
                    // properly formatting the mac address
            StringBuilder macAddress = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i =0; i < mac.length; i++){
                macAddress.append(String.format("%03X%s", mac[i],(i < mac.length -1) ? "-":""));
            }
            System.out.println("Hardware adrress: " + macAddress.toString());
        }
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------");
    }
}
```

}

The output of the code in kali linux 2.0 is:
----------------------------------------------------
Interface Name: wlan0
IPv6 Address: fe80:0:0:0:1992:d9bc:7d8c:d85b%wlan0
IPv4 Address: 192.168.1.137
Hardware adrress: 078-0E4-000-0E7-0B0-046
----------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------
Interface Name: lo
IPv6 Address: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo
IPv4 Address: 127.0.0.1
----------------------------------------------------